# bash: running a command with quotes and variables

Tags: bash

I have this line at the end of my bash file:

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 'https://example.com/?bot_id=$BOT_ID&page_id=$PAGE_ID'
```

Since I have 2 parameters in my query string, I need to surround the URL with quotes.

The problem is the bash is outputting the variable name (`$BOT_ID`) instead of the value of it.

How could I output the value inside the quotes?

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes so the shell expands the variables; using single quotes keep the value as-is

```
[root@box ~]# a=5
[root@box ~]# echo '$a'
$a
[root@box ~]# echo "$a"
5
```

> **Rule of thumb:** always double quote your variables in bash.

[from TLDP docs:](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)
When referencing a variable, it is generally advisable to enclose its name in double quotes. This prevents reinterpretation of all special characters within 
the quoted string -- except $, ` (backquote), and \ (escape).

Answer (score 0):

you should use "" :

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 "https://example.com/?bot_id=$BOT_ID&page_id=$PAGE_ID"
```